# Hiding Status Bar in iOS with Actionscript/Flash Builder

Tags: ios, flash-builder, statusbar

I've been playing around with trying to remove the status bar in iOS while compiling with Flash Builder. The problem is that I need the status bar to be there sometimes, but only during certain views does it go away, so just setting the true in the application xml file will not work.
I've also tried using stage.displayState = "fullScreen", and stage.displayState="normal". This works in the emulator, but when I test on the actual device, the stage.displayState never changes from its original state.
Anyone know of a way to do this, or if it's even possible using Flash Builder?
If not directly through actionscript, does anyone know of an ANE (air native extension) that would be able to toggle the status bar for both iOS and Android?

Also, for more information, I'm using Flex 4.6/AIR 3.4 SDK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really late, but for anyone still looking for a solution to this issue, there is an ANE that allows you to do this. https://github.com/sharkhack/IOSStatusBarAne

To use it, simply call `com.azer.IOSApplicationSettings.Settings::StatusbarHidden("YES");`